# Angular 2, Spring Boot, JPA, Hibernate or PHP Angular 2, MYSQL

Tags: php, angular, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am doing my final year project at Monash, and below is the technical issue i am having currently.

I am planing to develop e- learning solution which can expose and consume API and 3 rd party APIs. Approach is on my mind is - Angular 2 - PHP, RESTful and Mysql

But my college says , you better go with Angular 2 - Sprint boot, RESTful, JPA, hibernate and Mysql

So, please tell me , what would be the best approach.

Can I still use Angular 2, PHP, RESTFul API and Mysql.

Thank you and awaiting your favorable response.

Comment: JPA and hibernate are same. Hibernate is implementation of JPA. Also, you are missing a tag of Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use which one you want, it comes down to your preferences and the type of your project, whether you need php more or spring more, or whether you're good in php and not in java for example.

- Angular(now in version 5) and php as backend (that exposes the restful API)
- Angular(frontend) and spring boot(backend)

Are both valid

if you want to do it with php there is some useful frameworks to help you create your API like [laravel](https://laravel.com/) for example